# Typescript Object is possibly 'undefined' after check

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-beautiful-dnd, immer.js

Quick question - why Typescript still thinks it will be undefined?

When added code below to my application I have Typescript Error on line `draft.splice(result.destination.index, 0, draggedItem);` saying that `result.destination` Object is possibly undefined. This is partially true as it is typed like this: `DragUpdate.destination?: DraggableLocation | undefined`. However, I do a check at the very beginning of this function so at a given line it will never be `undefined`.

```
const onDragEnd = useCallback((result: DropResult) => {
        // do nothing if no destination
        if (!result.destination) return;
        setState((prevState: IOrderCard[]) =>
            produce(prevState, draft => {
                const draggedItem = draft[result.source.index];
                draft.splice(result.source.index, 1);
                draft.splice(result.destination.index, 0, draggedItem);
                return draft;
            })
        );
    }, []);
```

This is React app with hooks, using also `immer` and `react-beautiful-dnd`.

Comment: You're using callback and typescript don't know/ can't guarantee that the `result` won't change. Quick fix - extract `result.destination` to its own variable or use non-null assertion operator

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment to what Alexsey L. said but an even quicker fix is to just use ! when you know something will be defined.

Comment: Perhaps this is a quick fix, but you neither explained its implications, nor provided even the smallest example.

Comment: This is called non-null assertion operator  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator